# Can't find GoogleService-info.plist in Xcode 9.0?

Tags: firebase, plist, xcode9

I just update to Xcode 9 and after installing Firebase libraries the project can not find the GoogleService-info.plist file, even if it is there!! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please click GoogleService-info.plist in Xcode and see the right side panel.
on there you can find Target Membership area.

and please make that as checked state like this image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Instead of dragging the Google file into your Xcode project, right click the folder (inside your Xcode project) that you would like to save the Google file and click "Add Files to '[App Name]'..." and add GoogleService-info.plist that way. Also make sure the file is called "GoogleService-info.plist".